# Kendo Progress bar in Angular not in sync with SignalR response

Tags: angular, signalr, kendo-progressbar

I am using a kendo progress bar in my angular project. The Value property is bind to a property of a component.

The same property is getting updated by subscribing the SignalR events.

In my local environment progressbar is updating as expected. But the progressbar updates very slow or sometimes directly from 1 to 50 in production environment.

I have checked with logging the values coming from signalR, and there is no delay in SignalR.

It seems progressbar is not updating properly for some reason.

Anybody has any idea on this, Please help.